# How to handle shared jar file in maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project base on Ant build ,I want to change the build tool from Ant to maven,But there is a big problem .
I have a jar file in my project ,and it can be modified by multi developers.
The jar file is located on special system and there is text file beside it.
Every time each developer change the jar file ,he/she set the flag(is Editing?) inside the text file to true while editing the jar file.
When he/she finished editing the jar file,he/she set the flag inside the text file to false,and then copy it to lib folder in project.
How could I handle this process in maven repository ?

Comment: That process is not supported with a maven repository. I hope the source code is under version control...Apart from that make a maven project which builds the jar file and every time a developer needs to change it make a new version of it and it will be deployed to your internal repository (use a repository manager).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about the process. But you can try to use Maven Ant run plugin. I t will help you to mimic ant build.

Comment: If I use maven ant run plugin,what about concurrency?How can I show other developer the jar file is being edited or not ?(The jar file is produced by a simple java application which receive .xml file and produced .jar file)